# Variables in a list

Tags: regex, string, list, vim, substitution

I would like to put a set of variables in a list and do a substitute for each of them.
Example:

```
let mylist = ['var1','var2','var3']

for i in range(0,2)
 let mylist[i] = substitute(mylist[i], '\.', ',', 'g')
endfor
```

this must do this:

```
let var1 = substitute(var1, '\.', ',', 'g')  
let var2 = substitute(var2, '\.', ',', 'g')  
let var3 = substitute(var3, '\.', ',', 'g')
```

but it doesn't work.

What did I wrong?

**Edit**
The same variables ['var1','var2','var3']
have do to do more substitutes so I decided to add all substitutes in a list:

```
let mylist = ['var1','var2','var3']
let mySubst = [['\.', ','], ['\s*$', ''], ['[,.]0$', ''], ['^[.,]', '0&']]

for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1)
    for m in range(0,len(mySubst)-1)
      let mylist[i] = substitute(mylist[i] , mySubst [m][0],  mySubst [m][1], 'g')
    endfor
endfor
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
let [var1, var2, var3] = map([var1, var2, var3], 'substitute(v:val, "\\.", ",", "g")')
```

after re-reading the question, maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
let list = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
let [var1, var2, var3] = map(list, 'substitute({v:val}, "\\.", ",", "g")')
```

Comment: Hi El Isra, the first line did work The 2nd solution didn't. What will be the substitute command as there are 2 other variables in the command? p.e. `let [var1, var2, var3] = map([var1, var2, var3], 'substitute(v:val, searchvariable, replacevariable, "g")')` doesn't work

Comment: That substitution looks ok, so it's a bit hard to know why it's failing without more details. Can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: El Isra, I added more info in my question. Please see after Edit.

Comment: found it. Removed the `{}` around v:val and now it works fine! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have quotes around your variables on this line: `let mylist = ['var1','var2','var3']`. That makes them into string literals `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`, instead of the values of those variables.

Comment: This would be a great solution but removing the quotes didn't work :(